# MySQL Query: Getting COUNT of one table where the ID of table 1 has a value of X in a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress

I am working with Wordpress creating a filter and am struggling to figure out this raw query.

This is what I have now:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM active_listings 
   WHERE listing_type = "sales" 
     AND price > 50000 
     AND beds >= 3 
     AND baths >= 4 
     AND active = "1" 
     AND (dstatus IS NULL OR (dstatus != "Temporarily No Showings" AND dstatus != "Contingent")) 
     AND location in (11)
```

But I also need to check the `wp_postmeta` table to see if a row that has a matching `post_id` has the `meta_key` of `wpcf-active` and the `meta_value` of `1`.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: So wait a second - you're using a separate table called `active_listings`, but you are **also using** the `wp_postmeta` table? How are you doing that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an `INNER JOIN.` This will select the records from both tables that have the same post_id. You might have to adjust the column names, etc. but it will look roughly like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM active_listings INNER JOIN wp_postmeta
ON active_listings.post_id = wp_postmeta.post_id
WHERE listing_type = "sales" 
AND price > 50000 
AND beds >= 3 
AND baths >= 4 
AND active = "1" 
AND (dstatus IS NULL OR (dstatus != "Temporarily No Showings" AND dstatus != "Contingent")) 
AND location in (11)
AND meta_key = 'wpcf-active' 
AND meta_value = 1
```